# Realizar query con linq y C# para comparaciones

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy haciendo una pagina con Linq en C# con MVC pero necesito de una lista de cursos realizados compararla con la lista total de cursos para ver cuales le faltan! tengo este codigo pero solo me agarra uno

```
            var empleado = db.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == numReloj).ToList();
            var ID = empleado[0].ID;
            var employeec = db.Employee_Course.Where(x => x.ID_EMPLEADO == ID).ToList();
            var idcourse = employeec[0].ID_CURSO;
            var cursos = db.Courses.Where(x => x.ID_CURSO == idcourse).ToList();
            var cursor = cursos[0].ID_CURSO;
            var cursosjoin = db.Matrices.Where(x => x.ID_CURSO != cursor).ToList(); 
            return View(cursosjoin);
```

Alguien de alguna opcion que si agarre todos y no nomas el primero!

Comment: Crea una lista de cursosFaltantes y crea un for para que puedas recorrer toda la matriz de esta manera empleado[0] pasara a empleado[i], al faltante agregalo a la lista cursos faltantes, y despues se puede reducir la operacion pero primero es importante que visualices como estas identificando, agrega tu respuesta para despues simplificarla

Comment: Por qué no usar [.Except()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0)? Creí que eso se veía en teoría de conjuntos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya tienes las lista de los cursos que ha realizado el empleado y la lista de cursos que hay, lo unico que debes hacer es buscar los cursos que le faltan por cursar al empleado, puedes hacer esto:

```
var employeec = db.Employee_Course.Where(x => x.ID_EMPLEADO == ID).ToList();
var cursos = db.Courses.Where(x => x.ID_CURSO == idcourse).ToList();

var cursosFaltantes = cursos.Where(c=> !employeec.Any(e=>e.ID_CURSO == c.ID_CURSO) )
```

con esta ultima consulta obtendras los cursos que le faltan al empleado.